# how to reset web components over specified style with `all: initial`?

Tags: css, web-component

I’m building a widget that is aimed to be embedded on other websites. I’d like to avoid using iframe so I was looking at `all: initial`. 
“This keyword specifies that all property values set on the element all is set on — or inherited from the element's parent” seemed to be perfect but I’m having an issue when previous rules have a greater specificity.

here is an example of the issue:

```css
/* external css */
#color {
  color: red;
}

span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

span {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

/* my widget css */
/* reset */

widget,
widget * {
  all: initial;
}

/* then my widget style */
widget span {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  Lorem <span id="color">ipsum</span> dolor sit amet,
  <widget>consectetur <span id="color">adipiscing</span> elit.</widget>
  Phasellus eget velit sagittis.
</div>
```

At this point the only style inside the widget should be the word “adipiscing” printed in blue the text-decoration has as intended be cleared but it’s still red and bold

I’ve tried prefixing the rules with ids it kinda work, but not for the `!important` rule. I also tried to add `!important` in some or each of the widget rules but it only makes things worst

Is there a way to make this work without touching at the external css?

Answer (score 1):

Give your elements higher specificity paired with !important.

```css
/* external css */
#color {
  color: red;
}

span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

span {
  font-weight: bold !important;
}

/* my widget css */
/* reset */

widget,
widget * {
  all: initial;
}

/* then my widget style */
widget span {
    font-weight: initial !important;
}

widget span#color {
     color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  Lorem <span id="color">ipsum</span> dolor sit amet,
  <widget>consectetur <span id="color">adipiscing</span> elit.</widget>
  Phasellus eget velit sagittis.
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately I don’t know what will be present in the external so I can’t add `!important` on the `widget span`, but it seems to work if I add it to the `all: initial`. I was hopping to avoid this but I’ll do more test to see if it works all the time

Comment: The `!important` on the `widget span` is there to combat the one that targets the entire `span` tag. If at all possible I would get rid of that.

I'll remove the `!important` on the `#color div` which isn't required.

Comment: the point of the first part of the css is that it’s css I don’t control, it’s here to represent css already on the website. I can’t edit it and I can’t even know what will be there. so I can’t target individual rules from there. also I can’t arbitrarily over specify `widget span` to `widget span#color` because I can’t know there is already a `span#color`